# How to add a height/width constraint with iOS Designer in Xamarin Studio?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin-studio

As the title indicates I want to add a constraint like with Xcode with the *Pin* button, but there is no such button in Xamarin Studio. I can't figure out where do I add a height constraint.

With height constraint I mean a constraint like

> viewA.height = null * multiplier + constant

i.e. `NSLayoutAttribute.NoAttribute` should be used!

How can I do that with iOS Designer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to left-click once on the heigth/width pin. Then the constraint is created for you with the current frame size.
**UPDATE:** In current Xamarin, when left-click on "I-bar" pin, you get two choices:
(1) "Width" (or Height), which creates a "Constant Width" (Height) e.g. "Width = 100", and
(2) "Aspect Ratio", which creates a Width-to-Height constraint, e.g. "Width = 1:1 * Height".

[image: See how you create the height constraint]

Comment: Is it possible to make the height or width relative to the size of the view? I see that you can make it relative to the size of a different control, but this feels like a hack. This is possible in Xcode, I think.

Comment: In the latest version of Xamarin it is possible to define an *aspect ratio* between height and width of the view. In my graphic above I only show how to create a width/height constraint for an item to itself (you only say it should have a width of 240 for example). I don't know how you can make it relative to a different control/view. In code you can, but with iOS Designer?

Comment: Thanks, I suppose it answers my question if you're not aware of any such feature either. I know you can make height/width relative to a different control (http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/designer/designer_auto_layout/#Size_Constraints), but I haven't found a way in Xamarin Designer to make the size relative to the parent view itself.

Using a constraint against aspect ratio in addition to size of a different control (e.g. a Label) is one possible workaround.