# Unable to find Horizontally in Container constraint in Visual Studio

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin.ios

I'm developing an app on Visual Studio with Xamarin, targeting iOS 6.
I'm trying to horizontally center an Image View inside of a View so that the image is in the center regardless of the device or orientation.

I found the following links which explains how to do it:

1. [How to add a height/width constraint with iOS Designer in Xamarin Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27172640/how-to-add-a-height-width-constraint-with-ios-designer-in-xamarin-studio)
2. [How can i center the content on a view controller so that it is always centered no matter what device size is used in xamarin storyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38666181/how-can-i-center-the-content-on-a-view-controller-so-that-it-is-always-centered)
3. http://mathewsanders.com/designing-adaptive-layouts-for-iphone-6-plus/

However, I'm unable to follow the instructions. They use Xcode and in visual studio I don't have the popup menu to add new alignment constraints or the menu to modify a constraint from within the layout section of the property menu.

I have also read the official doc from [Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/designer/designer_auto_layout/). However, dragging the middle square handle doesn't seems to allow me to create the "Horizontally in Container" constraint that I wish to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual Studio as well as with Xamarin Studio (using the IOS Designer) it is posible doing what you want.

Just insert the view you want to center (you can manually place it in the Horizontal center to save you a step later). Set the correct size and when you are ready to add the constraint just hit on the view (twice as you read in the documentation). Hold and drag the center square that appears on the view-to-center, as you stated, but be aware that to center the view horizontally you need to drag it to the vertical line (not the horizontal) that appears on the screen.

You will need to also add some other constrains like for the width and height of the view you want to center because without these it's difficult to know where to place your view.

Hope it's clear enough.